# subset a and group by data frame with multiple condition and multiple criteria in r

Tags: r, dplyr, subset

I have a dataset `df` with  multiple variables and unique IDs

```
ID  A   B   C   D
1   20  5   5.4 120.5
1   30  10  6.8 110.6
2   50  40  7.5 117.8
3   10  50  3.4 119
3   80  30  2.8 117.5
2   5   20  9.5 325.4
```

I can subset them by below code

```
new.df <- df[df$A < 56 & is.na(df$A) == FALSE,]
```

and I want the conditional column and subset the data frame by IDs

I Want the data frame with conditional column such as

```
ID =1 A=20 B=10 C=5.4 D=110.6
ID =2 A=5 B=40 C=9.5 D=325.4
ID =3 A=10 B=30 C=3.4 D=119
```

and output data frame should be

```
ID  A   B   C   D
1   20  10  5.4 110.6
2   5   40  9.5 325.4
3   10  30  3.4 119
```

can you guys help me out how it can be done

Comment: Can you explain what it the process behind your desired output? It is not clear to me why you want those 3 particular rows.

Comment: @user2974951 I want to subset the values in large colonies  the think i want only those datasets to perform statistical analysis with that set  alone

Comment: I don't understand. What is a conditional column? Are you trying to subset your data set by using specific criteria? Where did you get your last three lines from? For ex. row `1   20  10  5.4 110.6` does not appear anywhere in your first data frame.

Comment: I agree, your criteria does not make sense. for example, values of column A are `min` of ID, but for column D, it is the `max` of group ID=3 and ID=2 and the `min` for ID=1... can you clarify ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will give the output as a dataframe ,

```
df %>% group_by(ID) %>% summarise(minA=min(A), maxB = max(B), minC= min(C), minD = min(D))
```

Comment: @king_arrival27, using the same dataset, it does not provide the output you asked in your question.

Comment: @dc37 the dataset grouped by ID and interpreted as expected

Comment: @king_arrival27, so you have to correct the output you were looking for in your question because the column D for example is not what you're obtained with the code from Self, you should obtain 110.6 ; 117.8 and 117.5.